# How to change date format of a column based on regex in PostgreSQL11.0

Tags: postgresql, date, case, alter

I have a table in PostgreSQL 11.0 with following column with date (column type: character varying).

```
id   date_col
1    April2006
2    May2005
3    null
4
5    May16,2019
```

I would like to convert the column to 'date'

As there are two different date format, I am using a CASE statement to alter the column type based on a date pattern.

```
select *,
case
                when date_col ~ '^[A-Za-z]+\d+,\d+' then alter table tbl alter date_col type date using to_date((NULLIF(date_col , 'null')), 'MonthDD,YYYY')
                when date_col ~ '^[A-Za-z]+,\d+' then alter table tbl alter date_col type date using to_date((NULLIF(date_col, 'null')), 'MonthYYYY')
                else null
                end

from tbl
```

I am getting following error:

```
[Code: 0, SQL State: 42601]  ERROR: syntax error at or near "table"
  Position: 93  [Script position: 93 - 98]
```

The expected output is:

```
id   date_col
1    2006-04-01
2    2005-05-01
3    null
4
5    2019-05-16
```

Any help is highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can't alter a column one row at a time. Your better bet is to update the existing values so they are all the same format, then issue a single ALTER statement.